# Table shows id (auto-increment) is 0 in all rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I am using laravel 5.2 to develop my web application. i recently uploaded the web application from localhost to my hosting account. I also imported MySQL tables from phpmyadmin localhost to my phpmyadmin localhost in my hosting account.

When I opened my phpmyadmin I noticed that in one of my tables, the `id` (which is set to auto-increment) is not working. It is displaying 0 in all the rows.

When I set the `id` to auto-increment in phpmyadmin it gives me the following error:

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

#### Table structure in phpmyadmin

[image]

#### `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters this problem this is what you can do. 
select the table which id column is repeating "0". Select `STRUCTURE` at the top menu.
`Drop` the id field and create another id field which has an `A_I` (auto_increment) enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can not create AUTO_INCREMENT without a key so try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_application` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`project_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`team_leader` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`team_member` text,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`createt_et` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)
```

Hope this helps